# C++ function that determines the date

Tags: c++, function, loops

I'm trying to write a program that calculates a rental bill.  I have most of the program written, but I have to write a function that takes the user input of days rented and the starting rental date to determine the return date.  The only requirement is that the function is to be a loop that calls another function (that determines the number of days in the month). The problem I keep running into is that the other function (which is to determine the days in each month) doesn't change depending on the month.  So if I put in 1/1/2013, it has the correct number of days for the month and then when the counter changes to Feb, it continues with 31 days.  Does anyone know a formula that will satisfy the requirements?

Comment: Kindly go through FAQs before asking questions.

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: Lots of things that satisfy the requirements. However, maybe you need to post how you're calling the function and what it does.

Comment: There are many built in functions that do this - see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm . Convert the first date to seconds, add the number of seconds (24*3600*rentalDays), convert new time back to date.

Comment: @Iron Savior, there is nothing wrong with posting homework, as long as its an appropriate question. (Which this isn't, post the code you've written)

Comment: Iron Savior, I'm a student, but I'm not asking you to write my program.  I'm asking for a formula so I can write my program.  Floris, I've seen that before, but how does the number of days in a month carry over from one function to another?

For instance

     int year(int yearNum)
     {
              body
     }

     int month

     int day

     int dayRent

     int numOfDayMonth
     {
         extended if-else statement to determine the number of days to corresponding month
      }
      int finalDayRent
      {
          This is where the loop is to be that continues until the days end

Comment: Edit your question with the code that you've written.

Comment: Ahh Ok, Let me try that again

Comment: For some reason the indenting 4 spaces isn't outputting a code block

Comment: @user2649644 Try following the instructions on the right hand side of Question Editing section.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a hard-coded array with the number of days in each month.
Compensate for February's leap day and you should be good.

```
int daysInMonth(int month, int year)
{
    // Check for leap year
    bool isLeapYear;
    if (year % 400 == 0)
        isLeapYear = true;
    else if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
        isLeapYear = true;
    else
        isLeapYear = false;

    int numDaysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
    if (isLeapYear)
        numDaysInMonth[1]++;
    return numDaysInMonth[month - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not considering using [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html) ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use that since we haven't learned about that.  I'm only allowed to incorporate a program with a function determining the daysPerMonth and having that included in the loop for the next function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int isLeap(int year)
{ 
    return (year > 0) && !(year % 4) && ((year % 100) || !(year % 400));
}

int calcDays(int month, int year)
{
    static const int daysInMonth[2][13] = {
        { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 },
        { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 } };

    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
        return daysInMonth[isLeap(year)][month - 1];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this will give you the days of the month